# Disallow users to download, save or print document shown in an iframe

Tags: pdf, iframe, document

I'm showing pdf document in an iframe. The pdf resides in the same domain. I don't want to allow users to download, save or print the document.

I've removed `Print` and `Download` option from the top toolbar by applying CSS but still user can save or print the document on right click. I tried disabling right click using below code but it's not working on the iframe.

`document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());`

**Is there any way to disallow users to download, save or print document shown in an iframe?** Any help will be appreciated.